# The best way to remove duplicate values from NSMutableArray in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

The best way to remove duplicate values (`NSString`) from `NSMutableArray` in Objective-C?

Is this the easiest and right way to do it?

```
uniquearray = [[NSSet setWithArray:yourarray] allObjects];
```

Comment: You might want to clarify whether you want to eliminate references to the exact same object, or also those which are distinct objects but have the same values for every field.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without creating any copy of the array?

Comment: This way is enough easy and maybe best. But for example it won't work for my case - the items of array are not full duplicates and should be compared by one property.

Comment: Try this for once.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38007095/3908884

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Your `NSSet` approach is the best if you're not worried about the order of the objects, but then again, if you're not worried about the order, then why aren't you storing them in an `NSSet` to begin with?

I wrote the answer below in 2009; in 2011, Apple added `NSOrderedSet` to iOS 5 and Mac OS X 10.7. What had been an algorithm is now two lines of code:

```
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:yourArray];
NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [orderedSet array];
```

---

If you are worried about the order and you're running on iOS 4 or earlier, loop over a copy of the array:

```
NSArray *copy = [mutableArray copy];
NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;
for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    if ([mutableArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
        [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    index--;
}
[copy release];
```

Comment: If you need uniqueness AND order, simply use `[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array];` You can then get back an array via `array = [orderedSet allObjects];` or just use `NSOrderedSet`s instead of `NSArray` in the first place.

Comment: @Regexident's solution is ideal. Just need to replace `[orderedSet allObjects]` with `[orderedSet array]` !

Comment: Nice One ;)
I like the answer that make the developer copy&paste without a lot of modifications, this is the answer that every iOS developer will like ;)
@abo3atef

Comment: Thanks but you should fix you example. Reason - we usually have `NSArray` and should create temp `NSMutableArray`. In your example you work vice versa

Comment: Anyone know which is best view to remove duplicate is this method(using `NSSet`) or @Simon Whitaker [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10975302/3589771) prevent before add duplicate value which is efficient way?

Answer (score 78):

I know this is an old question, but there is a more elegant way to remove duplicates in a `NSArray` **if you don't care about the order**.

If we use [Object Operators from Key Value Coding](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) we can do this:

```
uniquearray = [yourarray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

As [AnthoPak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4894980/anthopak) also noted it is possible to remove duplicates based on a property. An example would be: `@distinctUnionOfObjects.name`

Comment: Yes, this is what I use too! This is a very powerful approach, which a lot of iOS developers do not know!

Comment: I was surprised when I learned that this could be possible. I thought that many iOS developers could not know this that is why I decided to add this answer :)

Comment: This doesn't maintain order of objects.

Comment: Yeah, it breaks the order.

Comment: Note that it can also be used like `@distinctUnionOfObjects.property` to remove duplicates by property of an array of custom objects. For example `@distinctUnionOfObjects.name`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AnthoPak, added to the answer :)

Answer (score 47):

Yes, using NSSet is a sensible approach.

To add to Jim Puls' answer, here's an alternative approach to stripping duplicates while retaining order:

```
// Initialise a new, empty mutable array 
NSMutableArray *unique = [NSMutableArray array];

for (id obj in originalArray) {
    if (![unique containsObject:obj]) {
        [unique addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

It's essentially the same approach as Jim's but copies unique items to a fresh mutable array rather than deleting duplicates from the original. This makes it slightly more memory efficient in the case of a large array with lots of duplicates (no need to make a copy of the entire array), and is in my opinion a little more readable.

Note that in either case, checking to see if an item is already included in the target array (using `containsObject:` in my example, or `indexOfObject:inRange:` in Jim's) doesn't scale well for large arrays. Those checks run in O(N) time, meaning that if you double the size of the original array then *each check* will take twice as long to run. Since you're doing the check for each object in the array, you'll also be running more of those more expensive checks. The overall algorithm (both mine and Jim's) runs in O(N<sup>2</sup>) time, which gets expensive quickly as the original array grows.

To get that down to O(N) time you could use a `NSMutableSet` to store a record of items already added to the new array, since NSSet lookups are O(1) rather than O(N). In other words, checking to see whether an element is a member of an NSSet takes the same time regardless of how many elements are in the set.

Code using this approach would look something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *unique = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableSet *seen = [NSMutableSet set];

for (id obj in originalArray) {
    if (![seen containsObject:obj]) {
        [unique addObject:obj];
        [seen addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

This still seems a little wasteful though; we're still generating a new array when the question made clear that the original array is mutable, so we should be able to de-dupe it in place and save some memory. Something like this:

```
NSMutableSet *seen = [NSMutableSet set];
NSUInteger i = 0;

while (i < [originalArray count]) {
    id obj = [originalArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([seen containsObject:obj]) {
        [originalArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        // NB: we *don't* increment i here; since
        // we've removed the object previously at
        // index i, [originalArray objectAtIndex:i]
        // now points to the next object in the array.
    } else {
        [seen addObject:obj];
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Yuri Niyazov [pointed out](https://twitter.com/YuriNiyazov/status/254259845870534656) that my last answer actually runs in O(N<sup>2</sup>) because `removeObjectAtIndex:` probably runs in O(N) time.

*(He says "probably" because we don't know for sure how it's implemented; but one possible implementation is that after deleting the object at index X the method then loops through every element from index X+1 to the last object in the array, moving them to the previous index. If that's the case then that is indeed O(N) performance.)*

So, what to do? It depends on the situation. If you've got a large array and you're only expecting a small number of duplicates then the in-place de-duplication will work just fine and save you having to build up a duplicate array. If you've got an array where you're expecting lots of duplicates then building up a separate, de-duped array is probably the best approach. The take-away here is that big-O notation only describes the characteristics of an algorithm, it won't tell you definitively which is best for any given circumstance.

Answer (score 21):

If you are targeting iOS 5+ (what covers the whole iOS world), best use `NSOrderedSet`. It removes duplicates and retains the order of your `NSArray`.

Just do

```
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:yourArray];
```

You can now convert it back to a unique NSArray

```
NSArray *uniqueArray = orderedSet.array;
```

Or just use the orderedSet because it has the same methods like an NSArray like `objectAtIndex:`, `firstObject` and so on.

A membership check with `contains` is even faster on the `NSOrderedSet` than it would be on an `NSArray`

For more checkout the [NSOrderedSet Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This got my vote, I read them all and it's the best answer. Can't believe the top answer is a manual loop. Oh they have now copied this answer.

Answer (score 19):

Available in OS X v10.7 and later.

If you are worried about the order,right way to do

```
NSArray *no = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:originalArray]allObjects];
```

Here is the code of removing duplicates values from NSArray in Order.

Comment: allObjects should be array

Answer (score 7):

need order

```
NSArray *yourarray = @[@"a",@"b",@"c"];
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:yourarray];
NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [orderedSet array];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayWithoutDuplicates);
```

or don't need order

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:yourarray];
NSArray *arrayWithoutOrder = [set allObjects];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayWithoutOrder);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Here i removed duplicate name values from mainArray and store result in NSMutableArray(listOfUsers)**

```
for (int i=0; i<mainArray.count; i++) {
    if (listOfUsers.count==0) {
        [listOfUsers addObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:i]];

    }
   else if ([[listOfUsers valueForKey:@"name" ] containsObject:[[mainArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]])
    {  
       NSLog(@"Same object");
    }
    else
    {
        [listOfUsers addObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have a sorted array, you don't need to check against every other item in the array, just the last item.  This should be much faster than checking against all items.

```
// sortedSourceArray is the source array, already sorted
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[sortedSourceArray objectAtIndex:0]];
for (int i = 1; i < [sortedSourceArray count]; i++)
{
    if (![[sortedSourceArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[sortedSourceArray objectAtIndex:(i-1)]])
    {
        [newArray addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

It looks like the `NSOrderedSet` answers that are also suggested require a lot less code, but if you can't use an `NSOrderedSet` for some reason, and you have a sorted array, I believe my solution would be the fastest.  I'm not sure how it compares with the speed of the `NSOrderedSet` solutions.  Also note that my code is checking with `isEqualToString:`, so the same series of letters will not appear more than once in `newArray`.  I'm not sure if the `NSOrderedSet` solutions will remove duplicates based on value or based on memory location.

My example assumes `sortedSourceArray` contains just `NSString`s, just `NSMutableString`s, or a mix of the two.  If `sortedSourceArray` instead contains just `NSNumber`s or just `NSDate`s, you can replace

```
if (![[sortedSourceArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[sortedSourceArray objectAtIndex:(i-1)]])
```

with

```
if ([[sortedSourceArray objectAtIndex:i] compare:[sortedSourceArray objectAtIndex:(i-1)]] != NSOrderedSame)
```

and it should work perfectly.  If `sortedSourceArray` contains a mix of `NSString`s, `NSNumber`s, and/or `NSDate`s, it will probably crash.

Answer (score 1):

There's a KVC Object Operator that offers a more elegant solution `uniquearray = [yourarray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];` Here's an [NSArray category](https://github.com/pm-dev/PMUtils/blob/master/Pod/Classes/Foundation%2BPMUtils/NSArray%2BPMUtils.m#L65-70).

Answer (score 1):

One more simple way you can try out which will not add duplicate Value before adding object in array:-

//Assume mutableArray is allocated and initialize and contains some value

```
if (![yourMutableArray containsObject:someValue])
{
   [yourMutableArray addObject:someValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove duplicate values from NSMutableArray in Objective-C

```
NSMutableArray *datelistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (Student * data in fetchStudentDateArray)
{
    if([datelistArray indexOfObject:data.date] == NSNotFound)
    [datelistArray addObject:data.date];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code of removing duplicates values from NSMutable Array.**.it will work for you. myArray is your Mutable Array that you want to remove duplicates values..

```
for(int j = 0; j < [myMutableArray count]; j++){
    for( k = j+1;k < [myMutableArray count];k++){
    NSString *str1 = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:j];
    NSString *str2 = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:k];
    if([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
        [myMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:k];
    }
 } // Now print your array and will see there is no repeated value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Orderedset` will do the trick. This will keep the remove duplicates from the array and maintain order which sets normally doesn't do

Answer (score -2):

just use this simple code :

```
NSArray *hasDuplicates = /* (...) */;
NSArray *noDuplicates = [[NSSet setWithArray: hasDuplicates] allObjects];
```

since nsset doesn't allow duplicate values and all objects returns an array

Comment: Worked for me. All you have to do is sorting your NSArray again as NSSet returns an unsorted NSArray.

Comment: Or simply use `NSOrderedSet`insteed of `NSSet`.