# i cannot remove duplicate objects in a NSArray iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I'm going crazy right now. I have a NSMutableArray with a bunch of Person objects. I want to remove the duplicated objects but it won't work. This is what i got:

```
NSMutableArray *withoutDoubles =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempResults];
    for (Person *person in temp) {
        if(![withoutDoubles containsObject:person]) {
            [withoutDoubles addObject:person];
        }       
    }
    for (Person *person in withoutDoubles) {
         NSLog(@"----> %@",person.name);
    }
```

That is not working, i still got duplicates. I also tried:

```
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempResults];
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:temp];
```

But it didn't work either. I need some help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your definition of a duplicate is two separate Person objects whose properties are set the same then the best way to achieve this is to override these two methods in your Person object

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject
- (NSUInteger)hash
```

which will allow you to properly achieve the compare.

You would then need to do the following

```
for (Person *personToTest in temp) {
    BOOL duplicate = NO;
    for (Person *person in withoutDoubles) {
        if ([personToTest isEqual:person]) {
            duplicate = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
        [withoutDoubles addObject:personToTest];
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have problem with isEquals: method. Two objects are equals, when both have same hash. [isEquals: documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that persons with the same name are really the same object (i.e. the pointer is pointing to the same address)?

Answer (score 0):

what is person ? any custom object ??? if so then add any unique ID in that class and then compare with that ID.

Comment: yes, it is a custom object. Should i override the `isEquals` method in the person class?

Comment: then try to access the object's unique field that is already available in ur mutable array and compare it with new object's unique filed..

Comment: ok i give up, i tried to do as you said but it didn't work i trid this `for (Person *compareThis in tempResults) {
        for (Person *toThis in withoutDoubles) {
            if (compareThis._id != toThis._id){
                [a addObject:toThis];
            }
        }

    }
` can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, i hope this may help you

```
    NSArray *copy = [mutableArray copy];
NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;
for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    if ([mutableArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
        [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    index--;
}
[copy release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just do it like this:

```
NSMutableArray*array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:person,person1,person2,nil];
NSMutableArray*array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:person1,person2,person,nil];

for (Person*person in array1)
{
    if ([array2 containsObject:person])
    {
         [array2 removeObject:person];
    }
}
```

This will remove all duplicates found in `array2`. You can also use `isEqual:` to compare the objects, that's up to you. Replace `array1` and `array2` with your two arrays and give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

One liner: `uniqueArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:temp] allObjects];`

Comment: This does not preserve the order.