# How to check for duplicate strings in an NSMutableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, duplicates

I have an NSMutableArray that I'd like to check for duplicate strings.  I don't need to know what the strings are, just if there are any duplicates.

I'm thinking add the answers to an NSSet, then check to see if the number of entries is different than the original array. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best way to remove duplicate values from NSMutableArray in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the code to see duplicates values**

```
for(int j = 0; j < [myMutableArray count]; j++){
      for( k = j+1;k < [myMutableArray count];k++){
       NSString *str1 = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:j];
       NSString *str2 = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:k];
       if([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
           NSLog(@"duplicate value is %@",[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:k]);
   }
```

}