# How NSSet compares values in array to remove duplicates when using SetWithArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, duplicates, nsset

I have NSArray and I want to remove duplicates from it. I know that using this method
    [NSSet setWithArray:[arrAllValues valueForKey:@"value"]]
I also know that it invokes method specified in valueForKey parameter. But I don't know what method NSSet invokes to compare objects in array.
    My problem is that I want to compare property named "value", but I want to return array of the object that contains the property and not the property. Can I do that?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Please refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compares them using the [NSObject protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a) method:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject
```

therefore, you can override this method in your class to implement the desired behavior, as a note just like you would do it in Java, you should also override hash.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Oscar!!! It worked!! I just didn't know what methods to override!!