# How to avoid duplicate elements in NSArray and print in a Table View Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

My Array element looks like this

```
 150,
150,
150,
571,
571,
571,
692,
692,
692,
123,
123,
123,
144,
144,
144,
147,
147,
147,
155,
155,
155,
542,
542,
542,
548,
548,
548,
551,
551,
551
```

And i need to display all the elements but not repeatedly same elements and it have to be printed in UItableView.Here is my code,

```
NSArray *array=[jsonarray valueForKey:@"ID"];
cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
```

Here my jsonarray have various fields among that ID is one.Guidance Please..

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best way to remove duplicate values from NSMutableArray in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSSet.  From Apple's doc: NSSet declares the programmatic interface for static sets of distinct objects. Like so:

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
```

Or:

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet alloc]initWithArray:array];
```

(Edited for completeness) And then:

```
array = [mySet allObjects]; //now you can continue using the array as previously
```

Comment: ya it solved my issue but if i tried to print in tableviewcell i'm not getting..NSArray *array=[jsonarray valueForKey:@"ID"];
    
    NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",mySet);

    cell.textLabel.text=[mySet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

Comment: You can try my following answer pass the newArray to the tableview

Answer (score 2):

I think the most elegant solution would be to use the `@distinctUnionOfObjects` operator on the array.

Basically,

```
NSArray *unique = [jsonarray valueForKeyPath: @"@distinctUnionOfObjects.ID"];
```

Should return an array of unique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well you got to store the data you want to display in your UITableView somewhere, in an data NSMutableArray for example. So you can loop over this json array and try to add objects to the data array. Each time you want to add a new item, you use following code:

```
- (void) addObjectToData: (NSObject *) obj {
     if(![data concontainsObject:obj]){
        [data addObject:obj];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily use an `NSSet` object which does not allow duplicates:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
```

And then iterate over the contents of the set.

Answer (score 1):

user523234 already posted good answer but you can also try following:

```
 for(int data in array)
 {
    if(![newArray containsObject:data])
    {
        [newArray addObject:data];
    }
 }
```

this should work.