# Objective-C NSArray remove object duplicates based on function

Tags: objective-c, arrays, underscore.js

It is clear from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c) that there are many ways to remove duplicates from an NSArray when the array's elements are primitive types, or when the elements are perfect duplicates. But, is there a way to remove duplicates based on a transformation applied to each element, as is permitted in [Underscore.js's uniq function](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq), rather than by simply comparing the whole elements? And if a manual implementation would be difficult to optimize, is there an efficient system-provided method (or 3rd party library algorithm) for accomplishing this that I am missing?

Comment: There can never be a "system-provided method" which is more efficient than manual, other than perhaps eliminating some loop overhead.

Comment: System-provided methods are almost always more efficient than manual, simply because a lot more work goes into them, and because they have access to private APIs we may not.

Comment: There's no "magic" in system-provided methods.  Just because you can replace a loop with a single method doesn't mean the actual code is any simpler or faster.  At best you save a few calls.  And in many cases a system-provided method is actually slower, because it must account for all sorts of edge cases you don't need to worry about.

Comment: I suppose, but I still don't see a need to reinvent the wheel if it isn't necessary (though it seems in this case that it is)

Comment: Every day here I see folks spending hours seeking help finding some sort of supposely-efficient, built-in mechanism for performing something that could easily be coded up in 5-10 minutes using plain vanilla statements.  Even if there is a "canned" solution, the time spent finding it is often not worth the effort invested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach:

```
NSMutableArray* someArray = something;

for (int i = someArray.count - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    MyObject* myObject = someArray[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        MyObject* myOtherObject = someArray[j];
        if ([myObject isSortaEqual:myOtherObject]) {
            [someArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            break;
         }
     }
}
```

Yes, it's N-squared, but that's not a biggie unless the array is fairly large.

Comment: (I'll let the reader figure out why the outer loop is backwards.  It's a technique I learned before many of you were born.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redefine what equality means for your objects, then consider overriding `-hash` and `-isEqual:`. Then you can create an `NSSet` from your array if order is irrelevant, or an `NSOrderedSet` if it is relevant. Here's an example of a Person class where I want the name of the person to determine object equality.

```
@interface Person
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation Person

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    Person *otherPerson = (Person *)object;
    return [self.name isEqualToString:otherPerson.name];
}

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [self.name hash];
}

@end
```

Uniquing them now is rather easy:

```
NSArray *people = ...;

// If ordered is irrelevant, use an NSSet
NSSet *uniquePeople = [NSSet setWithArray:people];

// Otherwise use an NSOrderedSet
NSOrderedSet *uniquePeople = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:people];
```

Comment: I gather that you don't mean to have `uniquePeople` defined twice, but are simply giving two alternatives?

Comment: Yeah that's to show a version without preserving order and one with. I'll update the code to clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You are looking for a way to pass your own method for testing for uniqueness (at least, that's what the `uniq` function you refer to does).

`indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` will allow you to pass your own block to determine uniqueness. [The result](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW24) will be an NSIndexSet of all the objects in the array that matched your test. With that you can derive a new array. The block you are passing is roughly equivalent to the Underscore iterator passed to `uniq`.

The sister method, `indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest:` also allows you to specify enumeration options (i.e. concurrent, reverse order, etc.).

As you mention in your question, there are lots of ways to accomplish this. [NSExpressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-224286) with blocks, [Key-value coding collections operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html), etc. could be used for this as well. `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` is probably the closest to what you seem to be looking for, though you can do much the same thing (with a lot more typing) using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up against this problem, so I wrote a category on NSArray:

```
@interface NSArray (RemovingDuplicates)

- (NSArray *)arrayByRemovingDuplicatesAccordingToKey:(id (^)(id obj))keyBlock;

@end

@implementation NSArray (RemovingDuplicates)

- (NSArray *)arrayByRemovingDuplicatesAccordingToKey:(id (^)(id obj))keyBlock
{
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[self count]];

    for (NSString *item in self) {
        temp[keyBlock(item)] = item;
    }

    return [temp allValues];
}

@end
```

You can use it like this (this example removes duplicate words, ignoring case):

```
NSArray *someArray = @[ @"dave", @"Dave", @"Bob", @"shona", @"bob", @"dave", @"jim" ];

NSLog(@"result: %@", [someArray arrayByRemovingDuplicatesAccordingToKey:^(id obj){ 
    return [obj lowercaseString];
}]);
```

Output:

```
2015-02-17 17:44:10.268 Untitled[4043:7711273] result: (
    dave,
    shona,
    jim,
    bob
)
```

The 'key' is a block that returns an identifier used to compare the objects. So if you wanted to remove Person objects according to their name, you'd pass `^(id obj){ return [obj name]; }`.

This solution is O(n), so is suitable to large arrays, but doesn't preserve order.